# Regex doesn't match strings with parentheses and \t

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this code to split strings using regex

```
suffixes = "(adj\.|adv\.|pron\.|num\.|num\.-m|conj\.|part\.|aux\.|prep\.|n\.|v\.|m\.)"
regex = f'^(\w+?)((?:{suffixes}) .*)$'
result = re.sub(regex, "\1#\2", re.escape(word), re.UNICODE).split("#")
```

The code works fine for almost all strings I have, but I'm facing a problem with these two strings: `'qiān\tnum. thousand'` and `'jiànm. (used for clothes among other items) piece'`. It seems like the pattern doesn't match, I think because of the special characters `\t` and `()`.

My expected result `['qiān\t', 'num. thousand']` and `[ 'jiàn', 'm. (used for clothes among other items) piece']`.

Comment: Why `re.escape(word)`? You are also using `re.UNICODE` as the count argument. Use `flags = re.UNICODE`, or simply remove it, it is redundant in Python 3.

Comment: Also, you need a raw string literal, `r"\1#\2"`, in the replacement

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for alerting me to `re.escape(word)`, I removed the escape, now just the first string (with `\t`) doesn't work

Comment: You could also shorten it a bit, and perhaps match the tab `([\w\t]+?)((?:ad[jv]|pron|num(?:-m)?|conj|part|aux|prep|[nvm])\.)` https://regex101.com/r/yZS2qs/1 You don't have to match the chars `(` and `)` because you are putting a `#` between group 1 and group 2 and then split the result again on `#`

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/TYac2g. I think you do not need `re.sub`, `re.search` will do. It is still not quite clear why do you want to include a TAB (whitespace) into  Group 1. What if there are more whitespaces (I understand all but regular space)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data came corrupt through some API. Easy fix: replace all tabs with `t` if you do not expect and tabs in the incoming strings.

Use

```py
import re
suffixes = r"(?:adj\.|adv\.|pron\.|num\.|num\.-m|conj\.|part\.|aux\.|prep\.|n\.|v\.|m\.)"
regex = fr'^(\w+?)((?:{suffixes}) .*)$'

for sentence in ['qiān\tnum. thousand', 'jiànm. (used for clothes among other items) piece']:
  result = re.search(regex, sentence.replace('\t', 't'))
  if result:
    print(result.groups())
```

See [Python code](https://ideone.com/J7dS5f).

**Results**:

```
('qiānt', 'num. thousand')
('jiàn', 'm. (used for clothes among other items) piece')
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding `\t` as [re.docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) says `\w` for Unicode (str) patterns

> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that
> can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the
> underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

`\t` is not character that can be part of word. So you need to add it. Try replacing `(\w+?)` using `([\t\w]+?)`